# How to check whether Flex AIR application is minimized to system tray or not?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air, nativewindow

I have an AIR Application in which i am monitoring a server. By Default, it will be minimized to system tray. Whenever server sends an alert, then minimized application in system should display a message similar to outlook(Alerts similar to, when a new message comes).

My problem is, How to check whether an AIR application is minimized to system tray or not.i have tried the following condition

```
if( this.stage.nativeWindow.displayState == NativeWindowDisplayState.MINIMIZED)
{
    //Write code here
}
```

But this code didn't work. The condition is always false. When i have debugged and tried to see the values of the displaystate, it is always having **maximized** state.

I am not sure, where i am doing wrong.

Can anybody, please help me to find out the condition for checking whether the application is minimized to system tray or not.

Comment: Hi Dinesh,
Have you done that in your project. i am asking you because you had worked on the similar functionality that i want. but i didn't know how to show the message so please help me to show the message in SystemTray. Please Reply me..

Comment: i have done it indirectly. It's just a workaround and it didn't give any problems till date.

Comment: If possible please post your code as answer on following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376422/create-a-notification-window-in-adobe-air-application

Answer (score 1):

if your window is not visible it doesn't necessarily mean it is minimized.

if the window is a lightweight window, you could simply manage it's visiblility by polling for the [NativeWindow's visible property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#visible).

---

more:  [Adobe AIR - Managing Windows](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e08.html)