# Create a Notification window in Adobe AIR Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex3

I want to create an AIR application in which i need to show the notification that when AIR application is minimize then at some interval of time message shows from the system tray similar like giving information.

I have visited this [LINK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html), its a nice component but tutorial is not that much good as component. I need to create a component like that or source is available from this site so modification in this component will also be acceptable. so please help me.

EG: When you minimize the Yahoo Messenger and some one is sign-out or sign-in then it gives notification i want component similar like that...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Step, We have created a Custom Popup control for Notifications display.

In the second step, we have controlled the display of that popup using the following code

```
if(!this.stage.nativeWindow.visible || this.stage.nativeWindow.displayState == NativeWindowDisplayState.MINIMIZED)
{
    stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
    fadeTimer = new Timer(5000,1);
    fadeTimer.start();
    fadeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fadePopUp);

    popUpWindow = new PopUpWindow();
    popUpWindow.isAlerts = true;
    popUpWindow.Message = "<b>You have "+event.numNewMessages+" new notification messages<b>";

    popUpWindow.type = NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;
    popUpWindow.open(true);
    popUpWindow.fadeInEffect.play();            
    popUpWindow.nativeWindow.x = Capabilities.screenResolutionX - popUpWindow.width - 10;
    popUpWindow.nativeWindow.y = Capabilities.screenResolutionY - popUpWindow.height - 35;
}
```

The condition used above is what we have used to find out, whether our application window is minimized to System Tray or not. Even though it is not a perfect fix, It didn't fail me yet. It's quiet stable for my app.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, but need some more help

here popupwindow is of which type? and also one more thing what is thirdEyeMessage and isThirdEyeAlerts?

Comment: Those are my Popup's properties. Basically they have used to set the Notification Message to display and Display style.

Comment: <mx:Window /> tag is used to create my custom Popup Window. It is MXML based component and available only in AIR based applications.